# Partial class for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to create a Partial class for the controller in MVC?

Reason : I have a controller which contains too many code. This controller contains the code for different reports and due to too many code it reduces the readability of the code. I want to keep controller name same for all reports so I want to distribute code for the different reports.

If i can do any other way than do let me know.

Thanks
Alok Shah

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can use a partial class - the compiler just merges them all up a compile-time to produce one.

However, you mention you want to 'distribute' code - if the code is to go into multiple projects then partials are not going to help.

You can instead create base controller classes (that inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` in a class library project, with the necessary action methods, and then simply use routing to route similar urls to different controllers.  [Here's a link to the Asp.Net Tutorial 'Creating Custom Routes'](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) which might be useful for that.  *I hightly recommend looking through the rest of the tutorial if there are other core aspects of MVC you're not sure about.  It doesn't cover everything, but it does the basics.*

A web application that needs to use those then simply has its own controllers inherit from those redistributable ones.  Even better, you can now create extensibility points through virtual methods etc if there are elements of these reports which different web apps might need to customise.

So `"Reports/Customers"` could route to a `CustomerReportsController` and `"Reports/Orders"` could route to an `OrdersReportsController`:

```
routes.MapRoute("CustReports",
  "Reports/Customers/{action}",
  new { controller = "CustomerReports", action = "Index", id = "" } );

routes.MapRoute("OrderReports",
  "Reports/Orders/{action}",
  new { controller = "OrdersReports", action = "Index", id = "" } );
```

This is the most simplistic approach to this problem - but I think using [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) (link is to MSDN walkthrough) would most likely also be applicable, in which case you might not need to use routing at all because the default route would probably do it all.

Comment: @Andras : Can I have some sample code or reference link for it? I never did custom routing so I do not have any idea about it.

Comment: Thanks Andras for your quick response but I already did in that way only. I am trying to understand that Areas things and looking quite complicated. :)

Answer (score 6):

Of course!

Partial classes are a feature of the C# language and bare no relation to MVC or any other framework you may be using.

Comment: .. That means I can create partial classes also for the Controller. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Partial classes are really just a feature of the language, and the compiled class is a regular .NET class like any other.

I would suggest though that you split the controller into multiple controllers, to ensure proper separation of concerns (having a class that is so big you need to split it up into multiple files will surely [smell bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).)

Answer (score 0):

"If I can do any other way than do let me know"

How about:

- Abstract away the "doing" parts to various report generators for the discrete report types, all of which conform to an Interface. These report generators will be classes sat outside of the MVC tier of the application.
- Clean up the controller so that the dependencies (Report generators) are injected in the constructor, using Ninject, StructureMap or Castle Windsor
- Clean up all of the report generation code out of the controller and into concrete implementations of the Report generator abstractions

You will then not need to split up your controllers into separate classes. The downside is that this will take a reasonable amount of time to conceptualize and implement, but you'll end up with a better codebase.

Comment: I am not able to catch up with you. Can you please provide me some sample code or sample application?

Comment: The difficulty here is in conceptualizing - I can't really give you a sample application, but I can point you to a decent explanation and example of a lot of what I've described (in better language, too) - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/117/Dependency-Injection-and-Inversion-of-Control-with-ASP.NET-MVC